# How to add multi value on input hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a sample code:

```
<input type="hidden" value="" name="stall_id">
<a href='javascript:;' onclick='check(this)' data-id='1'>Add</a>
<a href='javascript:;' onclick='check(this)' data-id='2'>Add</a>
<a href='javascript:;' onclick='check(this)' data-id='3'>Add</a>
```

My jquery:

```
function check(tr) {
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    $(tr).attr("onclick", "uncheck(this)");
    $(tr).html('Add');
}
function uncheck(tr) {
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    $(tr).attr("onclick", "check(this)");
    $(tr).html('Remove');
}
```

How to when check/uncheck, value will auto add on input hidden ?

Ex: `<input type="hidden" value="1,3" name="stall_id">` if I had checked two value.

Comment: Why not just use checkboxes?

Answer (score 0):

input type hidden can only have a literal value. If you use a comma separated string, you can elaborate it and transform it in an array. Alternatively you can use form input arrays. You can find some more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184670/html-php-form-input-as-array). Basically you'll need to create an input hidden (dynamically) for each value and set the name to "stall_id[]"

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change onclick attribute of `a` try this code will work fine for you use only single function:-

```
function check(tr) {
var id = $(tr).data("id");
var hdn = $('[name="stall_id"]'), val;
var text = $(tr).html();  
if (text == 'Add') {
     val = hdn.val() == '' ? id : hdn.val() + ',' + id;
 } else {
    val = hdn.val().split(',').filter(function (d) {
        return d != id;
    }).join(',');
 }   
 $(tr).html(text == 'Add' ? 'Remove' : 'Add');
   hdn.val(val);
   alert(hdn.val());
 }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Wky2Z/62/)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```js
function toggle(tr) {
  if ($(tr).hasClass("checked")) {
    $(tr).removeClass("checked").html("Add");
  }
  else {
    $(tr).addClass("checked").html("Remove");
  }
  var selected = [];
  $("a.checked").each(function() {
    selected.push($(this).data("id"));
  });
  $("input[name=stall_id]").val(selected.join(','));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="" name="stall_id">
<a href='javascript:;' onclick='toggle(this)' data-id='1'>Add</a>
<a href='javascript:;' onclick='toggle(this)' data-id='2'>Add</a>
<a href='javascript:;' onclick='toggle(this)' data-id='3'>Add</a>
```

We're attaching a class "checked" to checked elements so that we can simply select all checked elements using jQuery's class selectors.