# PHP: how to place value from form to array

Tags: php

i am trying to do within PHP page.I have form which contains radio button and i want to get their value and place in array. I dont know where i am doing wrong.

code:

```
   $example = array();
   $i=0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error())){
        $a= $row['A'];
        echo '<form method="get" action="?page=".$next."">'; 
        while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {

            echo '<div class="boxed" >';

            echo "\t".'<tr><th>'.
            $row['question']."<br>".
            '</th><th>'."<input type='radio' name= 't[]' value='{$row['A']}'>".$row['A']."<br>".
            '</th><th>'."<input type='radio' name='t[]' value='{$row['B']}'>".$row['B']."<br>".
            '</th><th>'."<input type='radio' name='t[]' value='{$row['C']}'>".$row['C']."<br>".
            '</th><th>'."<input type='radio' name='t[]' value='{$row['D']}'>".$row['D'].'</th>
            </tr>';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="page" value="'.$next.'">';
            echo '<input type="submit" name="submit"/>';
            $i++;

            echo '</div>';


            echo '</div>';
    }
    echo '</form>';
    if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
        $example[] = $_GET['t'];

        echo $example . 'chk';
    }


}
```

Comment: you should be getting errors displayed or written to your php error log. Start your debugging be looking in the error log

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Html/PHP - Form - Input as array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184670/html-php-form-input-as-array)

Comment: greenmaker i searched thats why i came here. Why did u anti vote? Shall i  report against u? and it is still open in my browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `.$example=$_GET['t'];` $example itself a be array. you can process it as you need

```
  if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
    $example[] = $_GET['t'];

    echo $example . 'chk';
}
```

to

```
  if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
      $example = $_GET['t'];

      for($i=0;$i<sizeof($example);$i++){
          echo $example[$i]."<br>";
      }

  }
```

or you  can use foreach also

```
if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
    $example = $_GET['t'];
    foreach ($example as $value) {
        echo "$value <br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: A `foreach` would be better that a `for` loop then size does not matter

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes you can go for foreach also. i edit foreach also now

Comment: Also you would need to do `echo $example[0][$i];` as you have coded it. Asuming `$_GET['t']` was the first thing placed in the `$example` array

Comment: @RiggsFolly echo $example[0][$i]; it is not required .echo $example[$i]; is enough. $example =$_GET['t']; is a 1D array

Comment: @Malik happy to help you :)