# Why isn't PHP receiving an array of values?

Tags: php, ajax

I am passing multiple values to PHP with the same name using ajax. But when I dump the array, only the last value is shown.

The serialized form:

> genres=59&genres=13&genres=15&genres=14&genres=16&genres=17&genres=18&genres=19&genres=20&genres=21&genres=22&genres=23&genres=24&accepted-media=1&special-instructions=&g-recaptcha-response=&userid=62&action=search

**PHP*

```
"genres=" . var_dump(array($_REQUEST["genres"])) . "\n";
```

> **array** *(size=1)*
>   0 => string '24' *(length=2)*

**JavaScript**

```
$("#form-enablers").on("submit", function () {
    $("#userid").val(localStorage.getItem("account-id"));
    var data = $("#form-enablers").serialize() + "&action=search";
    console.log(data);
    ajax('post', 'php/enablers.php', data, success, "Error searching: ");
    function success(table) {
        console.log(table);
        $('#table-list').empty().append(table);
        $("#writers-list").css({ "display": "block" });
    }
});
```

Comment: Needs to be `genres[]=` in the request.

Comment: It is, isn't it? Please elaborate.

Comment: See `genres[]=59`?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Please provide an answer.

Comment: Needs to be `genres=59[]&genres=13[]&genres=15[]&genres[]=14&genres[]=16...`

Comment: Instead of GET request, use POST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass an array of values in a request, a special syntax is required. You need to add **brackets []** to attribute name in order to put all attributes in an array.

In your case the serialized data should look like the following:

```
genres[]=59&genres[]=13&genres[]=15&genres[]=14&genres[]=16&genres[]=17&genres[]=18&genres[]=19&genres[]=20&genres[]=21&genres[]=22&genres[]=23&genres[]=24&accepted-media=1&special-instructions=&g-recaptcha-response=&userid=62&action=search
```

This way **$_REQUEST['genres']** will contain an array of values instead of a single value.

Comment: I changed the name to (<select id="genres" name="genres[]" multiple="multiple" required>) but the serialized string does not reflect genres[]=24. What am I missing?.

Comment: How are you serializing the data from the form?

Comment: I amended the question to include the ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

[Click here, is similar to your question though is not in Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184670/html-php-form-input-as-array)

The main point is the name of the values need to have square brackets [] .