# values are undefined in array type ids using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am changing src of an image after a colorbox is being closed. When ID of the `img` tag is like `tabImage` , it works fine but when I change the id to `tabImage[0]` it stop working.

Working code is as follow :

```html
<div class="whBg"><a href="javascript:openIframe('offerImage');">Select Image</a></div>
<form:hidden path="offerImageName" />
<form:hidden path="offerImageRel" />
<form:hidden path="offerImageTitle" />
<form:errors path="offerImage" cssClass="errorInst" />              
<img id="offerImages" src="" style="width: 642px; margin:0px 0 0 220px;" />
<input type="hidden" id="returnImageName" />
<input type="hidden" id="returnImageSrc" />
<input type="hidden" id="returnImageRel" />
<input type="hidden" id="returnImageTitle" />

<script>
  function openIframe(tabName)
  {
    $.colorbox({
      iframe:true, 
      href:"imageListFrame",
      innerWidth:1000, 
      innerHeight:500,
      onClosed: function() { 
        $("#"+tabName+"s").attr("src", $("#returnImageSrc").val());
        $("#"+tabName+"Name").val($("#returnImageName").val());
        $("#"+tabName+"Rel").val($("#returnImageRel").val());
        $("#"+tabName+"Title").val($("#returnImageTitle").val());
      }   
    });    
  }
</script>
```

When I change IDs of `input` and `img` it stop working.

```html
<div class="whBg"><a href="javascript:openIframe('toursImage',0);">Select Image</a></div>
<input type="hidden" id="toursImageName[0]" />
<input type="hidden" id="toursImageRel[0]" />
<input type="hidden" id="toursImageTitle[0]" />
<img id="toursImages[0]" name="toursImages[0]" src="" style="width: 642px; margin:0px 0 0 220px;" />
<input type="hidden" id="returnImageName" />
<input type="hidden" id="returnImageSrc" />
<input type="hidden" id="returnImageRel" />
<input type="hidden" id="returnImageTitle" />

<script>
  function openIframe(tabName,id)
  {
    $.colorbox({
      iframe:true, 
      href:"imageListFrame",
      innerWidth:1000, 
      innerHeight:500,
      onClosed: function() { 
        $("#"+tabName+"s["+id+"]").attr("src", $("#returnImageSrc").val());
        alert($("#"+tabName+"s["+id+"]").attr("src"));
        $("#"+tabName+"Name["+id+"]").val($("#returnImageName").val());
        $("#"+tabName+"Rel["+id+"]").val($("#returnImageRel").val());
        $("#"+tabName+"Title["+id+"]").val($("#returnImageTitle").val());
      }   
    });    
  }
</script>
```

I have double checked that `returnImageName`, `returnImageSrc` etc are getting right values. I tried to access value of `#toursImages[0]` using jquery but I am getting `undefined` in alert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape the `[]` - Brackets with `\\`

```
$("#"+tabName+"Name\\["+id+"\\]")
```

From jQuery Docu: [LINK](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as 
>   !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must
>   be escaped with with two backslashes: \\.

Comment: Thanks . I really appreciate for your quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can't put `[` and `]` in the `id` attribute.

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/79022/863110

Try to replace it to underscore (`_`) for example:

```
<input type="hidden" id="toursImageName_0" />
```

Comment: Then wht should I implement here ? It is essential to add multiple `toursImageName` because I am mapping it to a `List` in spring MVC. Is there any way to add multiple `<input type="hidden" id="toursImageName[count]" />` ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with  spring MVC but it's not make any sense that it works with invalid html. Usually, when you work with multiple instances, the `name` attribute contains those characters `name=collection[0]` See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20184680/863110

Comment: Thanks to provide your valuable time. Actually in Spring MVC I know only one way to bind a list (There may be another ways). Anyway issue has been resolved. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should change `toursImageName[0]` to `toursImageName0`.