# Php and mysqli forms

Tags: php, mysqli

I have created a form for users to populate a database and can display it back in table form. What I'm trying to do is get it to populate a form, preferably one record at a time so I can validate the information (accept it to a final searchable database) or decline (delete from initial database)

At present I don't want to be handed the code as I am trying to learn how to do it. Really I am just after information as to whether this is possible to do.

The end result is going to be a searchable database but I need a way of manually verifying that the data is correct and relevant to the site. Any advice on how best to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: "If it is possible": yes it is, ask for the advice, there are plenty of tutorials out there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible.

Your question is quite broad, but as you said you don't want code but rather just a push in the right direction so you know it's possible I'll give some pointers:

- It sounds like you have an HTML table, each row is a form corresponding to the columns of a database table?
- To populate this HTML form you require an SQL `SELECT` query - see http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp
- When looping through the results with the `while()` loop in PHP, you would echo a new HTML table row `<tr>` and print the form as well.

  - A form array - [Html/PHP - Form - Input as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184670/html-php-form-input-as-array) - may be useful for you
- When you submit the validated data - see http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp - you will want to loop through each of the `$_POST` form items and perform your validation
- If there are no validation errors you can then `UPDATE` (or `INSERT` depending on the nature of your script) the database data - see http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Good luck!

Comment: Your answer is well formed and give some general advises to start make a working code. But, please, [don't link to W3Schools website](http://www.w3fools.com/) !