# PHP getting dynamic $_POST content

Tags: php, post

So I'm trying to get dynamic data from the $_POST array. The $_POST array looks like this after the form submit:

```
Array
(
    [teams1member3] => on
    [teams1member4] => on
    [teams1member7] => on
    [teams1member8] => on
    [teams2member1] => on
)
```

Now I'm not entirely sure how I can access these, the teams can be any number and the same goes for a member. Is there a way to "read" the `[teams1member3]`?

I tried looping through the $_POST variable with a foreach loop (`foreach($_POST as $post)`), but this only gets the value (`on`). If I'm able to get the `teams1member3`, `teams1member4`, etc. I should be able to continue.

Anyone that can help me out? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [`$key => $value` syntax](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $post){
   // $key is what you need
}
```

But you should rather serialise your `$_POST` data better, consider using the following JSON notation:

```
{
  "teams" : [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "members": [3, 4, 7, 8]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "members": [1]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: So I have a bunch of the following checkboxes: `<input type="checkbox" name="teams1member1" />`. Depending on whether they are checked or not I want them to be visible in an array. Is this possible to do through HTML or am I going to have to do something with JS/PHP to make this possible?

Comment: w/o JSON, [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184670/html-php-form-input-as-array).

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    // ...
}
```

`$key` will contain array keys (what you need), `$value` - string "on".

Answer (score 1):

if you just use `foreach($_POST as $value)` , you will only get the values - in your case on and off

However, if you want the actual field name, you have to specify key and value in your foreach:

```
foreach($_POST a $key => $value) {
  //$key contains teammember
  //$value contains on
}
```