# Make an array from input field

Tags: php, html

I want create an array like this from input field.

```
$array = array(
    array (
        'menu_primary' => 'Primary 1',
        'menu_secondary' => array( 'Secondary 1', 'Secondary 2', 'Secondary N' ),
    ),

    array (
        'menu_primary' => 'Primary 2',
        'menu_secondary' => array( 'Secondary 1', 'Secondary 2', 'Secondary N' ),
    ),

    array (
        'menu_primary' => 'Primary N',
        'menu_secondary' => array( 'Secondary 1', 'Secondary 2', 'Secondary N' ),
    ),
);
```

I try this method, but not working fine.

```
<input type='text' name='front_page_options_settings[menu_primary][menu_primary][]' value=''>
    <input type='text' name='front_page_options_settings[menu_primary][menu_primary][menu_secondary][]' value=''>
    <input type='text' name='front_page_options_settings[menu_primary][menu_primary][menu_secondary][]' value=''>

    <input type='text' name='front_page_options_settings[menu_primary][menu_primary][]' value=''>
    <input type='text' name='front_page_options_settings[menu_primary][menu_primary][menu_secondary][]' value=''>
    <input type='text' name='front_page_options_settings[menu_primary][menu_primary][menu_secondary][]' value=''>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for loop and add the `key` of `primary` to `[]` instead.

```
<?php foreach($array as $menu_arrays): ?>
    <?php foreach($menu_arrays as $pri_key => $menu_array): ?>

        <!-- Primary Menu -->
        <input type='text' name='front_page_options_settings[menu_primary][<?php echo $key; ?>]' value='<?php echo $menu_array['menu_primary']?>'>

        <!-- Secondary Menu -->
        <?php foreach($menu_secondary as $sec_key => $secondary): ?>
        <input type='text' name='front_page_options_settings[menu_primary][<?php echo $key; ?>][]' value='<?php echo $secondary; ?>'>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    <?php ?>
<?php ?>
```

You can just remove the `echo` in value if you don't want it.
For getting the of array inputs. You can refer to this 
[Html/PHP - Form - Input as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184670/html-php-form-input-as-array)