# Same name text input submission in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

Hi i am submitting a form fields with same name

**Form**

```
 <form role="form"  class="m-t-20"  method="post"
                             action='<?php echo base_url();?>save'>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="chemistname[]" id="chemistname" class="form-control m-b-10">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="chemist_mobile[]" id="chemist_mobile" class="form-control m-b-10" pattern=".{10,10}" title="Enter 10 digit Mobile Number" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select class="form-control" name="typeofchemist[]" id="typeofchemist">
                        <option>Select Type of Chemist</option>
                        <option value="Attached">Attached</option>
                        <option value="Floating">Floating</option>
                        <option value="Institution">Institution</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="realtion[]" id="realtion" class="form-control m-b-10">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="chemistname[]" id="chemistname" class="form-control m-b-10">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="chemist_mobile[]" id="chemist_mobile" class="form-control m-b-10" pattern=".{10,10}" title="Enter 10 digit Mobile Number" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select class="form-control" name="typeofchemist[]" id="typeofchemist">
                        <option>Select Type of Chemist</option>
                        <option value="Attached">Attached</option>
                        <option value="Floating">Floating</option>
                        <option value="Institution">Institution</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="realtion[]" id="realtion" class="form-control m-b-10">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </form>
```

**Controller**

```
public function user_registration()
    {   
         $objDate = new DateTime();
         $employee_id = $this->session->userdata('employee_id');
         $usercode =$this->User_model->User_code();
         $form_data = $this->input->post();
        $args        = array('chemistname' => array('filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, 'flags' => FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY));
        $chemistname     = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST,$args);
        $args        = array('chemist_mobile' => array('filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, 'flags' => FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY));
        $chemist_mobile     = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST,$args);
        $args        = array('typeofchemist' => array('filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, 'flags' => FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY));
        $typeofchemist     = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST,$args);
        $args        = array('realtion' => array('filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, 'flags' => FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY));
        $realtiont     = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST,$args);
        //You may need to check this part
        $newArray=array();
        $i=0;
        foreach($chemistname as $rowChemistName){
        $newArray[$i]['chemist_name']=$rowChemistName;
        $newArray[$i]['chemist_mobile']=$chemist_mobile[$i];
        $newArray[$i]['typeofchemist']=$typeofchemist[$i];
        $newArray[$i]['realtion']=$realtiont[$i];
        $i++;
        }
        echo'<pre>';print_r($chemistname);
        echo'<pre>';print_r($newArray);exit;

}
```

I need to get these inputs as single array and to be inserted as individual rows in the database

How should i get those values into an array by using foreach loop or any other condition to get the data as an array

Am using codeigniter-3, am using post method and am calling the controller and parsing the data and inserting into database

I have same three scenarios of this kind, after form submission the data is not pushed into newArray

Comment: unable to get your query pls be precise and provide some more details

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184670/html-php-form-input-as-array?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: I think you kinda misused the "[]" in input-name.

Comment: You have two rows with the same type of inputs is it ok?

Comment: Yes I have two rows with same inputs @pradeep

Answer (score 0):

With your current HTML structure you can access and group the data like this:

```
// Loop the chemistname and use $k to extract data from the other inputs in this same position
foreach( $_POST[ 'chemistname' ] as $k=>$v )
{
    echo $k.': '.$_POST[ 'chemistname' ][ $k ].' '.$_POST[ 'chemist_mobile' ][ $k ].'<br>';

    // You can use the $_POST example from my echo statement to build your DB insert
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use php **filter_input_array**  to process html array into php.
Extract all the field individually first next try to rebuild an array with this value to process further in php.
Sample code given bellow.

```
$args        = array('chemistname' => array('filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, 'flags' => FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY));
$chemistname     = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST,$args);

$args        = array('chemist_mobile' => array('filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, 'flags' => FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY));
    $chemist_mobile     = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST,$args);

$args        = array('typeofchemist' => array('filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, 'flags' => FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY));
$typeofchemist     = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST,$args);

$args        = array('realtion' => array('filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, 'flags' => FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY));
$realtiont     = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST,$args);
//You may need to check this part
$newArray=array();
$i=0;
foreach($chemistname as $rowChemistName){
    $newArray[$i]['chemist_name']=$rowChemistName;
    $newArray[$i]['chemist_mobile']=$chemist_mobile[$i];
    $newArray[$i]['typeofchemist']=$typeofchemist[$i];
    $newArray[$i]['realtion']=$realtiont[$i];
    $i++;
}
```

all the above variable will be array

Comment: I have implemented the above code but the values are not returning and am getting the data from the form in this way $form_data['chemistname'], Should i Change INPUT_POST to $form_data@Prithwis

Comment: Input_post is your form method. Check if it is get or post in your form. Where did you stuck?

Comment: am submitting the form except this data all the data is been displayed am using post method @Prithwis

Comment: try print_r($chemistname) and other three other array $chemist_mobile , $typeofchemist   and $realtiont . If you are able to get data from this variable then go to next step with foreach loop

Comment: am not getting the data can i share the code to you @Prithwis

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169496/discussion-between-sairam-duggi-and-prithwis-chatterjee).

Answer (score 0):

Try this once form get submitted, hope so you get your answer.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>demp</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="">
        <input type="text" name="d[]">
        <input type="text" name="d[]">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['submit']))
{
    echo '<pre>';
    $d_array = $_POST['d'];
    $d_store_values = array();
    foreach($d_array as $key => $d)
    {
        $d_store_values[$key] = $d;
        //insert query
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tablname (dvalue)
        VALUES ($d)";

        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) 
        {
            echo "New record created successfully";
        }
    }
    print_r($d_store_values);
}
?>
```