# HTML/PHP - Form input as array, need comma separated values

Tags: php, jquery, joomla

I got a form like this:

```
<input name="form[AttendeesInstitution][]" type="text">
<input name="form[AttendeesInstitution][]" type="text">
```

When using Firefox Developer Tools I can see from my $_POST that I got a working array of values. My problem is that it is submitted to database like "Flexsus Brugsen". I need it to be comma separated values like this: "Flexsus, Brugsen".
I'm trying to build this in a limited Joomla component, so I can either do some jQuery just before _POST or some PHP on _POST. But I can't find a solution :-(

[image]

[image]

EDIT: Removed HTML id's

Comment: You cannot have elements with the same id as an FYI.

Comment: First thing - ids should be unique (perhaps a typo) .

Comment: Second thing - the issue then is with your backend processing script, because the data looks to be submitted properly to the backend. Can we please see your backend processing script?

Comment: I got inspiration from this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184670/html-php-form-input-as-array answer by @Hanky Panky. And it is working just fine and submitted to Joomla like: "firstvalue secondvalue". So I don't understand what you mean with cannot have same IDs.

Comment: They mean a HTML `id` attribute like this `id="AttendeesInstitution"` should be unique to the whole page. Otherwise js code will not work properly if you attempt to use a duplicated `id`

Comment: Can you get any values? When in the PHP code can you do a `print_r($_POST)` and give us the output?

Answer (score 0):

Please set different ID for each element and after that you will be able to use this code.

Here is how you can do it

```
<?php
     $post = array(); 
     foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
         $post[$key]= $post[$key].', '.$value;
     }
     /* Now $post will look as what you want*/
 ?>
```

Comment: Do not work. See my second image for PHP options in this component.

Answer (score 0):

You can use php implode() function

```
<?php
...
implode(",",$_POST["form"]["AttendeesInstitution"]);
...
?>
```

Comment: are you sure that your form data is sending with post?

Comment: Yes, see image.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are assuming that `$_POST` is being set like

```
$_POST["form"]["AttendeesInstitution"][]
```

In actuality I would imagine it is being set like (I would need to see the output of `print_r($_POST)` to be certain).

```
$_POST["form[AttendeesInstitution]"][]
```

So the way you are accessing it should be throwing an `Undefined index`

You have two options to fix this

Loop the array like you have it but probably not what you want:

```
foreach($_POST["form[AttendeesInstitution]"] as $k=>$v){
    //Stuff you do here
}
```

or update your forms input to make the data the way you want because `$_POST` is already an array.

```
<input name="[form][AttendeesInstitution][]" type="text">
<input name="[form][AttendeesInstitution][]" type="text">
```

I cannot 100% test this either.

Comment: I tried to change name attribute of my input, then nothing was saved to database. So I don't think I can change that. I guess SQL code of Joomla component looks for a name like started in my question. So I think the loop is the answer. But my trying to implode it does not work. My full form can be found [here](http://shop.kbhmadhus.dk/kurser/tilmeld/1160-nordic-assembly-2018). In the grey section you can click "Add another", this is giving the multiple input array fields for companyname. I need to be able to separate the participants by comma. It acctually goes for all the fields in this form.

Comment: @Henrik If you are using Joomla  you should tag your question appropriately. What about the other way of parsing the `$_POST` I gave? If that does not work then can you do a print of what post looks like? There is not enough information here to help.

Comment: Yes, I might use your parsing $_POST. But I maybe implode it wrong. My POST looks like the first image I attached. 0:Flexsus 1:Brugsen. That is the params in my array. I don't understand way I have this problems adding a ', ' to the input value. It should be simple to do in the foreach loop.

Comment: @Henrik assuming that you are loop correctly what is the output of `$post` when you are done? FYI a `print_r($_POST)` is more familiar to a lot of us for debugging and helping us only helps you.

Answer (score 0):

in your joomla controller, you should get the data like this:

```
$formData = $this->input->post->get('form', array(), 'array');
$attendeesInstitution = implode(',', $formData['AttendeesInstitution']);
```