# Loop through CheckBoxes changing tag

Tags: vba, ms-word, contentcontrol

I'm trying to change the Tag of a bunch of CheckBoxes (Content Control), so the tags match the CheckBox row position on a table.

Ex.: If CheckBoxes are positioned on row 4, i want all of them to have the same tag (like Row4,or something like that).

**Is this possible or the Tag property is only for reading purpose?**

*I'll be gratefull on any advise. Thanks in advance!*

Image of the table bellow

[image]

Comment: [you can type name as Array in the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184670/html-php-form-input-as-array)

Comment: I assume your checkboxes are content controls. You can find a lot of vba manipulation of Content Controls on Greg Maxey's site to get you started. http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/content_controls.html  I expect that your question will be closed without answers. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I did something wrong on this question?

Comment: Typically when posting your problem it's good to include (eg) some code you already tried, or what research you did to try to solve it before posting, and what *specific* problem you're having when trying to implement what you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic example:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim cc As ContentControl, i As Long, tbl As Table, rw As Row
    
    Set tbl = ThisDocument.Tables(1)
    For Each rw In tbl.Rows
        i = i + 1
        For Each cc In rw.Range.ContentControls
            If cc.Type = wdContentControlCheckBox Then
                Debug.Print cc.Tag
                cc.Tag = "Row_" & i
            End If
        Next cc
    Next rw
End Sub
```